# Changes in view files not reflected in playframework project

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am working on play 2.4 and it often happens that changes done in main.scala.html file are not reflected when the project is run.

I have to compile the project on somebody else's system and then it works fine.Can anyone tell me the reason and solution for this?

Comment: in your project directory, use command "sbt clean", then run it agagin.

Comment: Are you sure that you always run command `sbt ~run` not  the `sbt run` ?

Comment: Thanks! I used cleanFiles command of activator and it worked,the changes are reflecting now.Can you tell me how to avoid this in first place?

Comment: @user1869107 sorry, I don't know how to avoid this case. I think you can update the answer to help the others who met the same problem as you. By the way, please upvote my comments, thanks.

Comment: Ok, Thanks! I just did :)

Answer (score 1):

cleanFiles command in activator did the work for me.
Now, the changes done in view files are showing.